# Make XML payload fields case insensitive when mapping to Java Object in REST API developed using SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, xml-parsing, jaxb, mapping

Because of history reason, we must adapt old sys. This is the xml request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<User>
    <Age>18</Age>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <PassWord>string</PassWord>
    <UserName>
        <FirstName>Maxwell</FirstName>
        <LastName>xxx</LastName>
        <MiddleName>string</MiddleName>
    </UserName>
</User>
```

Now, we need to implemente the consumer-service with springboot. But it didn't support payload case insensitive when mapping to bean.

```
@Data
public class User{

    private Username UserName;

    private String PassWord;

    private int Age;

    private String Gender;

    @Data
    class UserName{

        private String LastName;

        private String MiddleName;

        private String FirstName;
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

I know I could use @XmlElement, but it will have some issue when integrate with swagger @annotation.

I would like to map the XML payload to Java Object directly using @RequestBody Spring annotation. My question here is How do I make the java Object to map to the fields ignoring the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call .configure(MapperFeature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES, true) to the ObjectMapper to be case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I found the way to handle this issue. We could import jackson-dataformat-xml into pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.6</version>
</dependency>
```

If don’t use jackson-dataformat-xml, SpringBoot automatically uses JAXB of JDK to convert XML. It will case sensitive.